# "Really + (Object)" vs "Really just +(Object)"

Tags: word-choice

I'm really a driver now.

I'm really just a driver now.

Which one would a native english speaker use or widely used in english speaker environment ?

Comment: I think they will say *I really **am** a driver now,* or *I'm just a driver, really,* depending what they want to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine myself using either one, but they would mean different things:

> I'm really a driver now.

I would say this sentence if I just turned seventeen and got my driver's license. (I'd probably end it with an exclamation point!) It expresses some happiness that I'm finally a driver, as if I had been feeling like the day would never come.

> I'm really just a driver now.

I would say this sentence if I previously did more than just drive, and now that's all I do. It might express a degree of regret or disappointment in the situation.